# How to uncompress 7zip file on older unix?

Tags: ubuntu, version, 7zip

I'm transfering 7zip files from a remote server to another one, but I don't find any way to uncompress those files.

The problem is that files have been created, I guess, with a recent version of 7zip, while the installed version on the other server is 9.20. Also this second server is running trough Ubuntu 12.04 and I did not find any way to run a more recent version of 7zip, is it possible or not ?

I do not have the hand on the first server so I can't just use another zip software, and I can't neither download all files on my computer then unzip->zip and upload again because it would be too long.

So is there a way to unzip recent 7zip archive into ubuntu 12.04 ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

7-Zip 9.20 was released on the 18 November 2010. So, I don't think the problem is with the version. 7-zip has a lot of options for creating of an archive. And some other programs may not support some options. So, if your files were compressed by 7-Zip than try to uncompress them by 7-Zip. 7-Zip on Ubuntu is "7z". You can install it using commands in Linux console:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install p7zip-full
```

If this package was installed than you can uncompress your files using command in Linux console:

```
7z x <path_to_archive>
```

Public support of Ubuntu 12.04 LTS was ended on the 28 March 2017 and maybe before installation of **p7zip-full** you need to change **/etc/apt/sources.list** (make a backup copy before changing!!!) where change **archive.ubuntu.com** and **security.ubuntu.com** to **old-releases.ubuntu.com**

Comment: Tested working solution: This is a working instruction for installing and extracting file by using 7zip https://kompjuteras.com/en/how-to-install-latest-7-zip-version-on-centosredhat-linux